# when is a verb combined with würden in subjuntive mood?

Tags: subjunctive

When we say something about an imaginary situation we use *Konjuntiv II.*
(like in English, "if I were a bird, I could fly to the island".)

I read in a German grammar book that when a verb's Konjuntiv II form is not distinguishable from the past form, we should use 'würden + Inf.' instead of the Konjuntiv II form.
For example,

English:

> If she could speak German, she would get a job.

German:

> A: Wenn sie Deutsch sprechen könnte, würde sie eine Arbeit bekommen.
>   B: Wenn sie Deutsch sprechen könnte, bekäme sie eine Arbeit.

The book seems to say, A is correct but B is wrong. Why is B wrong, even though *bekäme* is distinguishable from *bekam*? I can't understand it exactly.

Comment: I think you misread something, because the Konjunktiv II is always distinguishable from the past form. In fact, I would prefer B, but A is also correct.

Comment: Wow, then the book I have (a German book written in Korean) seems to have an incorrect explanation! Thanks.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Not distinguishable: _»Hätte ich Geld, kaufte ich das Auto.«_ So better: _»Hätte ich Geld, würde ich das Auto kaufen.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer, in deinem Beispiel ist _würde kaufen_ nicht die Ersatzform für den K II von _kaufen_, sondern der K II von _werden_ (Futur). _Wenn ich Geld habe, werde ich das Auto kaufen_ wird zu _Hätte ich Geld, würde ich das Auto kaufen_.

Comment: For strong verbs and modals the Konjunktiv II is usually distinguishable from the preterite (käme/kam, könnte/konnte) wheras for weak verbs it's usually not (kaufte/kaufte).

Comment: @Pollitzer, aber ja, offensichtlich gibt es identische Formen. :-)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Was ist z.B. mit dem Verb "gehen"? KII ist: "gingen", und Präteritum auch. Ich nütze fast immer die würde-Form.

Comment: @Pollitzer Can you give an example that is actually indistinguishable, if context is considered? "Kaufte" in "Hätte ich Geld, kaufte ich das Auto" cannot be a past form, because the sentence wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: Then just consider this dialogue: _»Sag mir einen zweideutigen Satz!«_ – _»Ich kaufte das Auto.«_ Or: _»Meine Schwester sagte, sie kaufte das Auto nicht.«_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is also right. But it sounds a bit old-fashioned/stilted/written-language. People actually use type A in common real life. I think that is why your book wants you to use A although it's not wrong to use B.

Comment: *Bekommen* is one of the verbs where people actually use the Konjunktiv forms, even in speech: *Ich bekäm' dann noch fünf Euro.*

Comment: @Janka: Nee, verwende ich nie. Aber habe ich schon gehört, wobei mir die Verwendung in dem Fall sehr formelhaft vorkommt